# How to get reliable indentation in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation, auto-indent

I'm new to Emacs.

I'm trying to write an elisp function that works across all modes. Specifically, I want to write a function that inserts braces (a bit like `insert-parentheses`) in the same way the following key sequence does for a dumb editor that only supports auto-indent:

```
"{" <ret> "}" <up-arrow> <end> <ret> <tab>
```

This key sequence works for both Java and C# (bsd) style indentation. I need it to work in all brace-y emacs modes, and also in plain text files - I have other formats that have no emacs modes but still use braces.

Here's my 12th attempt or so:

```
(defun insert-braces-macro ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "{")
  (newline)
  (indent-relative t)
  (insert "}")
  (forward-line -1)
  (end-of-line)
  (newline)
  (indent-relative t)
  (indent-relative nil))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work quite right. I don't think `indent-relative` is the right function, because it doesn't indent correctly in Java-style:

```
f |
```

expands into:

```
f {
  |
}
```

and in C mode:

```
somelongword another |
```

expands to:

```
somelongword another {
             |
}
```

But `indent-according-to-mode` isn't right either, because it will indent too much in C-ish modes (the trailing '}' is indented) and not at all in Fundamental mode.

What's the right way to handle this?

Comment: Is it because different modes have different default indentations unless the user sets them specifically?  `(defun my-tabset-hook () (setq indent-tabs-mode t) (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 2 200 2)) (setq tab-width 2) (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab) )
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'my-tabset-hook) (add-hook 'tex-mode-hook 'my-tabset-hook) (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-tabset-hook)`

Answer (score 4):

`indent-according-to-mode` is the right answer, I think, but you need to remember that it can't predict the future, so you need to call it *after* inserting the text rather than before:

```
(defun insert-braces-macro ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "{")
  (newline) (indent-according-to-mode)
  (save-excursion
    (newline)
    (insert "}")
    (indent-according-to-mode)))
```

Comment: To be frank, I'd prefer to disable emacs' smart indenting altogether. It's too unpredictable and doesn't work in fundamental mode. I can use dumb auto-indent with my eyes closed and know what it does no matter what the source code is written in...

Comment: indent-according-to-mode doesn't indent at all in fundamental mode

Comment: If you use `fundamental-mode`, that's a problem in itself.

Comment: If the indentation is unpredictable, then it's a bug, which you should report.  If it's predictable but different from the style you like, of couse, that's another problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've been using for a long time:

```el
(defun ins-c++-curly ()
  "Insert {}.
Treat it as a function body when from endline before )"
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back "\\()\\|try\\|else\\|const\\|:\\)$")
      (progn
        (insert " {\n\n}")
        (indent-according-to-mode)
        (forward-line -1)
        (indent-according-to-mode))
    (insert "{}")
    (backward-char)))
```

This function:

1. inserts a `{}` block when looking back
   at a place where it's appropriate, e.g. after a `)`.
2. otherwise, inserts `{}` and goes backward one char.
   Useful for arrays and the new-style initialization.

This works for C++, where I have indentation set to 4 spaces,
as well as for Java, where I have it at 2 spaces.

Comment: indent-according-to-mode doesn't indent in Fundamental mode, so it is no good for my purposes. Unless it can be made to indent in fundamental mode?

Comment: What are your purposes then? I imagine that curly braces means code, and why write code
in fundamental mode? How would you want to indent in fundamental mode?
I could slap an `(if (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode) ...)` onto the code, but I'm
not sure what to do afterwards.

Comment: I use curly braces in dumping ASTs from compiler front ends, and other bracketing constructs in other ad-hoc file formats. There are too many to be writing major modes for them, much less configuring all those modes.

Comment: I'm going to try and take this in a different direction. I asked another question about disabling smart indent altogether. If I can get a dumb autoindent mode working in Emacs, I can solve this problem for once and for all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945380/how-to-get-auto-indent-not-smart-indent-in-emacs-in-all-modes