# How to configure Emacs 24 to K&R(or Stroutrup) style?

Tags: c++, emacs, elisp, emacs24, yasnippet

I want the code like this.

`for (;;) {`

}

But YASnippet always output this.

```
for (;;)
{

}
```

Is there a way to change the C++ style?

This is my .emacs file.

`(setq c-default-style "stroustrup")`

(add-to-list 'load-path
         "~/emacs/yasnippet/")
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd just have to edit the snippet for yourself.
It's located in `snippets/cc-mode/for`.
Here's how mine looks like:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
#name : for (...; ...; ...) { ... }
# --
for (unsigned int ${1:i}=0; $1<${2:N}; ++$1)$0
```

I insert the braces separately with a function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18941046/1350992),
since sometimes you need braces and sometimes not.