# How to get auto indent (not smart indent) in emacs in all modes

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation, auto-indent

I'm new to emacs, and its indenting is driving me up the walls. It's too smart for its own good; it (incorrectly) thinks it knows how I want to format my source, but I don't have time to chase down every setting for every mode for every different language that I write code for; and many of those languages don't have any mode enabled at all.

Here's the behaviour I'd like:

- TAB inserts *indent*
- RET inserts a new line then copies the blank characters from the start of the previous line to the first non-blank character, or end of line, whichever comes sooner
- DEL (backspace key) in the blank text between  line start and first non-blank character / end of line deletes one *indent* if possible, otherwise single character like normal
- No auto-indent on {
- No auto-unindent on }
- In fact, no smart-ass indenting behaviour anywhere anytime, just copy previous line's indent on RET.
- Two variables to be configured per source file format: *display tab width*, and contents of *indent*. Preferably these can be configured for random source code formats without having to write a major mode for them, unless writing a major mode is a one-liner in .emacs, consisting of two `setq`s.

This would get me logical and consistent behaviour across all languages. It would leave the work of formatting the code to me, but that's OK, I've been doing that for 20 years, and I know how to make other macros that make it efficient. More importantly, it saves me from endless fiddling with configuration settings trying to get the automatic behaviour to suit my preferences. And my macros can rely on consistent behaviour so they work correctly in all modes.

Is the above possible? Surely someone else has done this before? Is there some minor mode out there that makes it so?

Comment: If you don't like fiddling then Emacs isn't for you:).
But seriously, make your question more informative: add the modes that don't work.
I've used at least 15 different programming modes for Emacs and they're mostly great.
Or if you want to drop all the modes and stick to fundamental-mode, outline the
specific features of fundamental-mode that don't work for you.

Comment: @abo-abo I don't want to lose syntax highlighting or the ability to plug in things like auto-completion. But I spent over 15 hours the past two weekends trying to bash emacs into a reasonable shape, and it's still not suitable for switching between editing C and a brace-delimited language in Fundamental mode.

Comment: It's upsetting that the completion routine is also the tab routine. I rebound TAB to self-insert-command and rebound C-<space> (C-@) to indent-for-tab-command, and set tab-always-indent to complete, so I could get e.g. elisp completion in .emacs, but it also means C-<space> tries to auto-format. Whose bright idea was it to tie completion and code formatting into the same function?

Comment: First of all, it's a really bad idea to rebind `C-<space>`, as it serves
a very important role of marking the region. Secondly, there's no reason to spend
15 hours to bash Emacs into shape. The current state is the result of 30 year evolution
and usage by thousands of programmers. The problem is that you're trying to make Emacs
behave like whatever you were using before. Just take it one step at a time.
I can write below some code that re-binds the keys for all modes that you specify.
You can re-customize later if you want.

Comment: I've rebound set-mark-command elsewhere, but I don't use that marking style very often as I use transient mark mode. As to 30 years, thousands of programmers etc; that doesn't really matter to me, since I don't work like 99% of programmers; compiler engineer, Dvorak user, etc. My primary reason for taking up emacs is to get a programmable terminal editor, not for its mish-mash of half-baked UI modes. It is broken in its default state on Cygwin, and half the key bindings don't work inside screen, it was a lot of work just to get the terminfo settings right, never mind fix everything else.

Comment: I'm currently writing a minor mode to make indentation work as described in my question. We'll see how well it works in practice; I'll add my code as an answer once I'm finished.

Comment: Regarding the auto-indentation behavior of { and }, I'd consider these as bugs (it's a fine feature to have, but it should only be activated upon explicit request by the user, e.g. using `electric-indent-mode`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
(setq tab-width 4)
(defun plain-tab ()
  (interactive)
  (insert (make-string tab-width ?\ )))
(defun plain-ret ()
  (interactive)
  (looking-back "^\\( +\\).*")
  (newline)
  (insert (match-string 1)))
(defun plain-del ()
  (interactive)
  (backward-delete-char
   (if (looking-back (format " \\{%d\\}" tab-width)) tab-width 1)))
(defvar all-the-mode-maps
  '(c-mode-map c++-mode-map java-mode-map
    js-mode-map emacs-lisp-mode-map
    clojure-mode-map))
(require 'cc-mode)
(require 'js)
(require 'clojure-mode)
(eval `(mapc 
        (lambda(map)
          (define-key map [tab] 'plain-tab)
          (define-key map [return] 'plain-ret)
          (define-key map [backspace] 'plain-del)
          (define-key map "{" (lambda()(interactive)(insert "{")))
          (define-key map "}" (lambda()(interactive)(insert "}"))))
        (list ,@all-the-mode-maps)))
```

Comment: +1 for letting me know about a lot of useful forms. I'm going to incorporate much of it into my minor mode, with changes; e.g. some files use tabs rather than spaces; I'll use hooks rather than require to affect other modes, as emacs is non-instantaneous to start up as it is; and it'll need to affect bash, Haskell, OCaml, Ruby, Python, Go, JS, css, html, xml, xsd, scss, coffeescript, elisp, C#, yaml, erb, puppet, yacc, lex, awk, lua and makefiles, as an incomplete set of the file types that I've edited in the past month, not including file formats with custom parsers.

Comment: There's simply no way I have time to find major modes for all those formats and configure them each properly.

Comment: I guess that you'll have to write a minor mode that records all the modes that you use:)

Comment: You can define a global minor mode which rebinds `tab' to `plain-tab' etc... and then you don't need to care about listing the major modes you use.

Comment: You're right, @Stefan, I haven't actually gotten to write a minor mode yet, since most of what I write is specific to one mode.